# Type an API response and render it conditionally

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to type an API response and render it conditionally in a react component.

My API returns a Delivery Address which can be either a **Postal Address** with attributes : `type` (should be `"POSTAL"`), `street`, and `streetNumber`

**OR** a **Packstation Address** with attributes: `type` (should be `"PACKSTATION"`) `packstation`, and `postNumber`.

Here is my implementation for that :

(sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bird-dx2wp?file=/src/index.tsx:0-474)

**`types.ts`**

```
export enum AddressType {
  packstation = "PACKSTATION",
  postal = "POSTAL"
}

export interface PostalAddress {
  type: AddressType.postal;
  street: string;
  streetNumber: string;
}

export interface PackstationAddress {
  type: AddressType.packstation;
  packstation: string;
  postNumber: string;
}

export type DeliveryAddress = PostalAddress | PackstationAddress;
```

**`DeliveryAddressDisplay.tsx`**

```
import * as React from "react";

import { DeliveryAddress, AddressType } from "./types";


interface Props {
  deliveryAddress: DeliveryAddress;
}

const DeliveryAddressDisplay = (props: Props) => {
  // im trying to get the type of the address here so i don't recalculate the same thing in my JSX
  const isPostalAddress: boolean = props.deliveryAddress.type === AddressType.postal;
  const isPackstationAddress: boolean = props.deliveryAddress.type === AddressType.packstation;


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>
        {isPostalAddress && <span>Street: {props.deliveryAddress.street}</span>}
      </h2>
      <h2>
        {isPackstationAddress && (
          <span>Packstation: {props.deliveryAddress.packstation}</span>
        )}
      </h2>
      <h2>
        {isPostalAddress && <span>Street Number: {props.deliveryAddress.streetNumber}</span>}
      </h2>
      <h2>
        {isPackstationAddress && (
          <span>Packstation: {props.deliveryAddress.postNumber}</span>
        )}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DeliveryAddressDisplay;
```

`**index.js**`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { AddressType, DeliveryAddress } from "./types";

import DeliveryAddressDisplay from "./DeliveryAddressDisplay";

// my api response for example
const johnsAddress: DeliveryAddress = {
  type: AddressType.postal,
  street: "John's street",
  streetNumber: "17"
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<DeliveryAddressDisplay deliveryAddress={johnsAddress} />, rootElement);
```

With this implementation, Typescript is complaining when i try to do conditional rendering in my JSX about the types `street` and `streetNumber` that doesn't exist in the `PackstationAddress` type even though i'm trying to render a `PostalAddress`

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about the error that you get but if you do like this:

```
{props.deliveryAddress.type === AddressType.postal && <span>Street: {props.deliveryAddress.street}</span>}
```

then the error disappears.

Comment: yes, but it's an extra calculation in my jsx in every time im writing it, that's why i try to get that value in `isPostalAddress` varialble before and then use it in my jSX

Comment: what i think is that when you are trying to render conditionally may be for it `isPostalAddress` is just another boolean variable ,not a variable that holds any relation with AddressType.